# Need to remove ">" arrow in dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm currently working on a website:  http://www.psych.utoronto.ca/users/ferber

If you hover over the "Resources" tab on the main menu, you'll notice a drop down menu that I've coded.  However, for some reason the tabs on this drop down menu are accompanied by a ">" arrow and some added space at the top of the dropdown menu that turns grey when you hover over it.   I'm not sure why this is there, but I'd like to remove it and have the first tab of the dropdown menu sit flush against the parent tab.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's the CSS stylesheet:

```
/*Keeps vertical scrollbar present to prevent page shifting*/
html { min-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px; }

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
}


#menu{
    width: 800px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding:0px;
}

#main {

    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#innerLeft {

    float: left;
    width: 590px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#innerRight {   

    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-left:thin solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    overflow: hidden;

}

ul#nav,ul#nav li{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0}

ul#nav{margin-left: 0px;width:800px}

ul#nav li{float:left;margin-right: 3px;text-align: center;list-style: none outside none;position:relative;}

ul#nav a{float:left;width: 6em;padding: 5px 0;background: #B0C4DE;text-decoration:none;color: #000}

ul#nav a:hover{background: #E7F1F8;color: #000}

ul#nav li.activelink a,ul#nav li.activelink a:hover{background: #000000;color: #FFFFFF}

ul#list,ul#list li{list-style-type:none;margin-left:0px;margin-top:8px;padding:0}

ul#pub,ul#pub li{list-style-type:none;margin-left:0px;margin-top:12px;padding:0}  

/* ------- Dropdown Menu-------- */
#nav li:hover {background:#777;}

#nav ul {
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
top:1em;
list-style:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
display: inline-block;
left: -40px;
position: absolute;

}


/* ------- calendar specific styles -------- */

a.cal:link {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
a.cal:visited {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
a.cal:hover {text-decoration:underline;color:black;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:#DDDDDD;}
a.cal:active {text-decoration:underline;color:blue;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:white;}
```

And here's the code for the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="./"><img src="logo/SF_logo.gif" style="border-style: none" alt="Susanne Ferber - Cognitive Neuroscience Lab"></a>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li id="home" <?php if (curPageName()=="index.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="index.php">Personal</a></li>
    <li id="lab" <?php if (curPageName()=="lab.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="lab.php">Lab</a></li>
    <li id="publications" <?php if (curPageName()=="publications.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="publications.php">Publications</a></li>
    <li id="teaching" <?php if (curPageName()=="teaching.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="teaching.php">Teaching</a></li>
    <li id="people" <?php if (curPageName()=="people.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="people.php">People</a></li>
    <li id="Resources" <?php if (curPageName()=="resources.html") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?>><a href="facilities.php">Resources</a>
              <ul>                
                <li>  <?php ?>><a href="facilities.php">Facilities</a></li>            
               </ul></li>


</ul>
    <div id="innerLeft">
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: see `?php ?>>` you have extra >. Always pays off if you check your code carefully

Comment: Buy an IDE... It can help a lot to debug your code

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra ">" within this li, after this opening php tag

```
 <li>  <?php ?>><a href="facilities.php">Facilities</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have typed in the extra ">"

```
<li>  <?php ?>><a href="facilities.php">Facilities</a></li>
```

should be

```
<li>  <?php ?><a href="facilities.php">Facilities</a></li>
```

there on each line.

Answer (score 0):

You have `?>><a`, causing the `>`

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="./"><img src="logo/SF_logo.gif" style="border-style: none" alt="Susanne Ferber - Cognitive Neuroscience Lab"></a>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li id="home" <?php if (curPageName()=="index.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="index.php">Personal</a></li>
    <li id="lab" <?php if (curPageName()=="lab.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="lab.php">Lab</a></li>
    <li id="publications" <?php if (curPageName()=="publications.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="publications.php">Publications</a></li>
    <li id="teaching" <?php if (curPageName()=="teaching.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="teaching.php">Teaching</a></li>
    <li id="people" <?php if (curPageName()=="people.php") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="people.php">People</a></li>
    <li id="Resources" <?php if (curPageName()=="resources.html") { echo "class='activelink'"; } ?><a href="facilities.php">Resources</a>
              <ul>                
                <li>  <?php ?><a href="facilities.php">Facilities</a></li>            
               </ul></li>


</ul>
    <div id="innerLeft">
```